nodejs sequelize node beforeConnect hook not working
I am trying to retrieve creds and configure in this 2 ways but its not working.
Now getting any logs from this when I run the lambda!
import * as seq from 'sequelize';
import { retriveCredentials } from '../secretManager/retrieveSecret';

export const sequelizeConnector = new seq.Sequelize(
    process.env.DATABASE_NAME as string,
    process.env.DATABASE_USER as string,
    process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    {
        host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
        dialect: 'postgres', // it actually takes type as dialect
        hooks: {
            //not working
            beforeConnect: (config) => {
                console.log('Init .. .. .', config);

                retriveCredentials(process.env.RDS_SECRET_NAME!).then((secrets) => {
                    console.log('Creds: ', secrets);

                    config.username = secrets.username;
                    config.password = secrets.password;
                    config.host = secrets.host;
                    config.port = secrets.port;
                });
            },
        },
    },
);

// not working
// gives this error: Property 'beforeConnect' does not exist on type  'Sequelize'. Did you mean to access the static member Sequelize.beforeConnect' instead?
sequelizeConnector.beforeConnect(async (config: any) => {
    console.log('Init .. .. .', config);

    const credentials = await retriveCredentials(process.env.RDS_SECRET_NAME!);

    console.log('Creds: ', credentials);
});

I am trying to connect to RDS PostgreSQL using sequelize connecter, retrieving credentials from secret manager. But beforeConnect hook is not getting executed.
I have "sequelize": "^6.37.3" in package.json.
Tried referring to some of the questions from the stackoverflow but not able to get through this.
Thanks in advance!

are values in secret manager is DB config?  if so why not call retriveCredentials before you initialize the sequelize.

@Emma The reason is I do not want to make any async function call in lambda initialisation. If I want to have connected with database before even lambda handler runs.

You might be able to work around on the async call but have you take a look at Sequelize doc for Lambda? https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/aws-lambda/  They are doing async initialization.  Sorry I am not answering your question but I think it is worth checking their official doc.
